# web start can't find jar file

Tags: java, html, java-web-start

I'm trying to use web start to run a java application on a remote device which is a Lantronix Xport Pro.  The Lantronix acts as a web server but it does not have a domain name, only an IP address which can change.  I can run my html file locally (with the jar and jnlp on local machine) and it works fine.  I can also run java web start at the command line and this works fine:

```
javaws http://192.168.1.100/TestGUI.jnlp
```

I can't get the jar file to load when I use my html page below remotely unless I add the line 'codebase="http://192.168.1.100"' to my jnlp file.  Of course I can't do this because the IP of the Lantronix is not fixed.  Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong or how I can resolve this?

A second related question is that application is going to need to know the IP address of the Lantronix also so how could I get that into one of the argument fields?

```html
<HTML>
<BODY>
<CENTER>
<IMG SRC='heading1.png'>
<a href="TestGUI.jnlp">Launch My Program</a>
</CENTER>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

JNLP file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
    <!-- JNLP File for My Program v1.0 -->  
    <jnlp  
    spec="1.0+"
    href="TestGUI.jnlp">  
    <information>  
        <title>TestGUI v1.0</title>  
        <vendor>CCG Technologies</vendor>  
        <homepage href="productpage.html"/> 
    <description>A program I wrote</description>
     <offline-allowed/>  
</information>  
<security>  
    <all-permissions/>  
</security>  
<resources> 
    <j2se version="1.7+"/> 
    <jar href="TestGUI.jar"/> 
</resources>  
<application-desc main-class="MyFrame">
    <argument>arg1</argument>
    <argument>arg2</argument>
</application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

Comment: *"I can't get the jar file to load when I use my html page below remotely unless I add the line 'codebase="http://192.168.1.100"' to my jnlp file. Of course I can't do this because the IP of the Lantronix is not fixed."* Then (of course) this will fail. JWS cannot work with ever changing IP addresses.

Comment: Thanks Andrrew.  The idea was the user will know the IP of the Lantronix and will use it to load the html file above ( for example http://192.168.1.100/TestGUI.html) which will then load the jnlp file.  My understanding was the codebase is optional and if not defined JWS will look for the jar file in the same location as the jnlp file.  However it looks like what's happening is JWS is looking for the jar file in the Windows temp folder where it copied the jnlp file.

Comment: Recently, for security purposes, the code base needs to be written in the manifest of the (digitally signed) Jar file.

Comment: Thanks, I had not read that but if true I will have no choice but to define the codebase and while our users will likely use fixed IP's they will have to edit the JNLP  file to change the codebase to the IP they choose.  Kind of funny because we had been using an applet but are migrating to JWS due to applet support being removed for security....now codebase must be defined for security.

Comment: This security update came in before browsers started dropping support for applets. It applied to them as well. It applied to *anything* with a security manager.